# decorator factory errors out for function arg's attribute

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-decorators

I have a simple decorator factory for a timer function. Sometimes, I get `TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable'` for the function argument, and I am not sure what I did wrong here:

```
def timer(capture_duration: bool=False) -> tp.Callable:
    def decorator(f: tp.Callable) -> tp.Callable:
        def handle_args(*args, **kwargs):
            start = time()
            print("Starting " + f.__name__) # error here
            
            ret = f(*args, **kwargs)
            end = time()
            
            print("Finished " + f.__name__ + f" in {end - start} seconds")
            
            if capture_duration:
                return (ret, end-start)
            else:
                return ret

        return handle_args
    return decorator
```

Somehow the decorator did not recognize (or it was not passed) into the factory, hence the fail in getting `f.__name__`.

Here's a sample usage:

```
timer(capture_duration=True)
def some_function_to_time(args):
    pass
```

Comment: Your "sample usage" doesn't work. Please fix the syntax errors.

Comment: The only way the line marked "# error here" could have produced the claimed error is if you had somehow assigned None to `print`.  `f.__name__` has nothing to do with it, as that's not any sort of call.

Comment: Thanks for adding the `def`. However, your code still doesn't give the error you claim. I get "Name error: tp is not defined". See https://replit.com/@codeguru/DizzyThoughtfulContent#main.py. Please [edit] your question to include a [mcve] that actually reproduces the error. Also include the full stack trace of the error.